# How can I register a View::composer from a Laravel package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package.json

How can I register a View::composer for use in a Laravel project from within a Laravel package?

In my package service provider I have a boot method with routes/views etc and this in the register function:

```
public function register()
    {

        $this->app->register(ComposerServiceProvider::class); 
    }
```

In the ComposerServiceProvider I have:

```
   public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            'admin.*', ProfileComposer::class
        );
    }
```

Which should load the ProfileComposer class into all admin.* views, but it's not working. It's definitely loading the class as a `dd('Test');` in the boot method shows the 'Test' message in the browser, just not applying the view composer.

I can't see anything in the Laravel documentation regarding loading View Composers from packages

This code has been extracted from my working laravel project for use as a package going forward but the view composers are causing issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A snippet from one of my own packages that works:

```
class ServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Factory $view)
    {
        $view->composer('template::name', ProfileComposer::class);
    }
}
```

The official docs don't mention packages, but it works exactly the same. The only difference is the place on the filesystem, but use the correct namespaces and you can just follow the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

Comment: That's all I was missing, the 'packagename::' view reference. Legend, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I have a related question here if you have any idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727138/add-an-all-views-wilcard-to-view-composers-from-within-a-laravel-package ;-)