# Add an all views wilcard to view composers from within a laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have a view composer working from within a package for a specific directory:

```
$view->composer(
        'cms::admin.*', ProfileComposer::class
    );
```

But I also have view composers that should be loaded across all root views, however the following are not being loaded as required:

```
$view->composer(
            'cms::*', NavigationComposer::class
        );

        $view->composer(
            'cms::*', SiteConfigComposer::class
        );
```

Any idea how to apply these view composers to all routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's across all route views, why restrict it to `cms::*`

try

```php
$view->composer('*', NavigationComposer::class);
$view->composer('*', SiteConfigComposer::class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work, 'cms' is the package name that the view composers are being loaded from. EDIT - ok this does actually work and I had tried this multiple times. Needed a composer dump-autoload! Thanks